# Is there a way to get an existing token for a user using the /tokens resource?

Tags: box-api

Is it possible to get an existing token for a user using the "/tokens" resource?

Currently, if a token exists, a 409 is returned by the POST:

Request:
POST https://api.box.com/2.0/tokens 
Body: {"email":"some-email-a-token-exist-for@email.com"}

Response:
{"type":"error","status":409,"code":"conflict","help_url":"http://developers.box.com/docs/#errors","message":"Token already exists","request_id":"1568559050e4a10f78f66"}

What I'd like to be able to do is make a GET request to retrieve the existing token.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, the /tokens endpoint is still in Beta.  Even though Box released the rest of the V2 API as GA in December, that endpoint is still being worked on.  We're working with a few developers to make sure we get the "instant access" mechanism easily useable, but also secure.

Let us know at api (at) box.com if you'd like to be on our /tokens advisory group.